# Writing a precise pointcut expression

Tags: spring, spring-aop, pointcut

I am using Spring AOP for logging wherein I want to log input/output of all methods present in package. I have written following pointcut for target package.

```
@Pointcut("within(com.mypackage.model.*)")
public void allmethods(){};
```

My logging method is as below.

```
@Before("allmethods()")
    public void LoggingAdviceBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) 
    {
        StringBuffer logMessage = new StringBuffer();
        if(joinPoint != null && joinPoint.getTarget()!=null && joinPoint.getTarget().getClass()!=null)
        {
            logMessage.append(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
            logMessage.append(".");
            logMessage.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            logMessage.append("(");
            // append args
            Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                logMessage.append(args[i]).append(",");
            }
            if (args.length > 0) {
                logMessage.deleteCharAt(logMessage.length() - 1);
            }

            logMessage.append(")");
            log.info(logMessage.toString());
        }

    }
```

The code is working fine.

My problem is, even if I do some simple operations like, populating an array list within my code, even that information is getting logged. I don't want such information to be logged.

I want to log inputs only for the methods that I had written in the classes present in target package & not for the code written inside those methods. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The AspectJ documentation is full of examples of more restrictive pointcut specifications. Have you read it?

Comment: I had done a basic search but didn't get what I wanted. Can you suggest a good website for enhancing my knowledge?

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/

Comment: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code which I had written months back to understand SNMP framework implementation, it prints i/o of all the methods in package and subpackage, you can remove irrelevant classes and modify according to your needs, if required.

```
@Aspect
public class Snmp4JProfiler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Snmp4JProfiler.class);

    @Pointcut("execution (* org.snmp4j.Snmp.*(..))")
    public void allSnmpServices() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution (* org.snmp4j.security.U*.*(..))")
    public void allUSMServices() {
    }

    @Around("allUSMServices() || allSnmpServices()")
    public Object executionTimeOfService(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        String className = pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
        final String methodName = methodSignature.getName();


        String methodArgs = "";
        for (Object obj : pjp.getArgs()) {

            if (obj == null) {
                methodArgs += "no args or null,";
            } else if (obj instanceof UsmTimeEntry) {
                UsmTimeEntry timeEntry = (UsmTimeEntry) obj;
                methodArgs += obj.toString() + "[" + timeEntry.getEngineBoots() + "," + timeEntry.getLatestReceivedTime() + ","
                        + timeEntry.getTimeDiff() + "," + timeEntry.getEngineID() + "]";
            } else if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
                methodArgs += obj.toString() + " " + Arrays.toString((Object[]) obj);
            } else {
                methodArgs += obj;
            }

        }

        LOG.info("Start of method#" + methodName + " #class#" + className + " #args#" + methodArgs);

        try {
            Object output = pjp.proceed();

            String rtValues = "";
            if (output == null) {
                rtValues += "no args or null,";
            } else if (output instanceof UsmTimeEntry) {
                UsmTimeEntry timeEntry = (UsmTimeEntry) output;
                rtValues += output.toString() + "[" + timeEntry.getEngineBoots() + "," + timeEntry.getLatestReceivedTime() + ","
                        + timeEntry.getTimeDiff() + "," + timeEntry.getEngineID() + "]";
            } else if (output instanceof Object[]) {
                rtValues += output.toString() + " " + Arrays.toString((Object[]) output);
            } else {
                rtValues += output;
            }

            LOG.info("End of method#" + methodName + " #class#" + className + " #return#" + rtValues);
            return output;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.info("End of method#" + methodName + " #class#" + className + " #error#" + ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik, after little modification the code is working fine :)